# Ayuda con esta query sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una duda con el ejercicio siguiente:

*Consciente de los gastos extras que los empleados deben enfrentar en el mes de Marzo, se desea  premiar al o los empleados con el monto de ventas más altas del mes de Marzo. Para ello, se desea saber el nombre, apellido y  monto total de las ventas efectuadas en el mes marzo de los empleados que cumplan con esta condición. La información se debe mostrar en el formato del ejemplo  y ordena en forma ascendente por salario y apellido:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la query que tengo, pero no logro obtener el resultado de la imagen de arriba.

```
SELECT
     E.PNOMBRE "NOMBRE",
     E.APPATERNO "APELLIDO",
    SUM( V.MONTO_TOTAL) "MONTO TOTAL VENTAS"
FROM EMPLEADO E JOIN VENTAS V ON(E.ID_EMPLEADO = V.ID_EMPLEADO)
WHERE(FECHA_BOLETA >='01032014' AND FECHA_BOLETA <='31032014')
GROUP BY E.PNOMBRE, E.APPATERNO;
```

Este es mi resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda ya que he intentado de todo pero no logro limitar a que solo me muestre la mayor venta ya que aún no entiendo bien el uso del `having`.

Comment: debes de especificar mejor el titulo de tu pregunta, desde ahi debes indicar un poco de tu problema o en lo que te gustaria que se te apoyara, el titulo tal como esta es muy ambiguo.

Comment: En lugar de una fecha estática se puede usar un número de mes, que reciba como parámetro, usando el año actual. Si puedes indica que sistema de bd usas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría así completando lo que ha puesto @ShinRaeJae_sunbae:

```
SELECT
   E.PNOMBRE "NOMBRE",
   E.APPATERNO "APELLIDO",
   SUM( V.MONTO_TOTAL) "MONTO TOTAL VENTAS"
FROM
   EMPLEADO E JOIN VENTAS V ON(E.ID_EMPLEADO = V.ID_EMPLEADO)
WHERE
   (FECHA_BOLETA >='01032014' AND FECHA_BOLETA <='31032014')
   AND "MONTO TOTAL VENTAS" = (SELECT TOP 1 SUM( V.MONTO_TOTAL) "MONTO TOTAL VENTAS"
   FROM
      EMPLEADO E JOIN VENTAS V ON(E.ID_EMPLEADO = V.ID_EMPLEADO))
   GROUP BY
      E.PNOMBRE, E.APPATERNO
   ORDER BY
     V.MONTO_TOTAL;)
```

De este modo lo que haces es obtener en la subconsulta el valor máximo de la suma total de las ventas, y luego en la consulta principal compruebas los empleados que hayan tenido ese total de ventas por si hay más de uno. No sé si he puesto comillas de más o de menos pero esa sería la idea.
Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta poner a final el order by

```
SELECT
    E.PNOMBRE "NOMBRE",
    E.APPATERNO "APELLIDO",
    SUM( V.MONTO_TOTAL) "MONTO TOTAL VENTAS"
FROM
    EMPLEADO E JOIN VENTAS V ON(E.ID_EMPLEADO = V.ID_EMPLEADO)
WHERE
    (FECHA_BOLETA >='01032014' AND FECHA_BOLETA <='31032014')
GROUP BY
    E.PNOMBRE, E.APPATERNO
ORDER BY
    'MONTO TOTAL VENTAS';
```

Comment: También necesita el `SELECT Top 1` para mostrar solo el que vendió mas.

Comment: Ojo: que nunca dice que solo quiera al primero
Para ello, se desea saber el nombre, apellido y monto total de las ventas efectuadas en el mes marzo de los **"empleados"** que cumplan con esta condición

Comment: Entiendo. Yo solo lo decía porque en el output deseado solo muestra un registro y la pregunta la termina con _"Agradezco su ayuda ya que he intentado de todo pero no logro limitar a que solo me muestre la mayor venta"_

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias a todos amigos, tome todos sus ejemplos y logre la query de esta manera:

```html
SELECT
    E.PNOMBRE "NOMBRE",
    E.APPATERNO "APELLIDO",
    SUM(V.MONTO_TOTAL) "MONTO TOTAL VENTAS"
FROM
    EMPLEADO E JOIN VENTAS V ON(E.ID_EMPLEADO = V.ID_EMPLEADO)
    WHERE(FECHA_BOLETA BETWEEN '01032014' AND '31032014')
GROUP BY
    E.PNOMBRE, E.APPATERNO
    HAVING MAX(MONTO_TOTAL) = (SELECT MAX(SUM(MONTO_TOTAL)) FROM VENTAS GROUP BY >MONTO_TOTAL);
```